# Rails 4. How to add authenticity_token to forms rendered via partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, csrf

On my rails app, on all pages, in the head section there are these 2 meta tags:

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="027GUZBeEkmv..." />
```

On forms not rendered using a partial there is a hidden `authenticity_token` field

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="D5TddQruJppDD3..." />
```

But this field misses if I simply load the form like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/comment_form' %>
```

Is this expected behavior ? Should I manually add an `authenticity_token` and if so how do I validate it ?

**Edit:**

**shared/_comment_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment], :html => { :onsubmit => "validateCommentForm(event)" }, remote:true) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Add to the article. Make it be more" %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-info" %>
<% end %>
```

Also, adding `<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" id="authenticity_token" value="ANYTHING" />` to that form still manages to post the info and create a new record...

Comment: You can send locals with a partial when called as such:

    <%= render'shared/comment_form, :locals => {:token => 'kasdlfjasldfj'} %

Comment: the `form_for` builder or `form_tag` usually takes care of adding a hidden field with an authenticity token, can you show us the form of `shared/comment_form` ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In your case, we have two ways to do:

1. Add `authenticity_token: true` in form options
2. Manually add authenticity_token field into form, like this:

`<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>`

Comment: Yes this is the solution, but also the explanation of what's going on is necessary to understand why this is happening and I have added that in an answer below

Comment: I thought `form_authenticity_token` was a placeholder for your actual authentication token but, surprisingly, this is an actual method that will return the session's CSRF token or generate one on the fly. Nice! https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L196

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so it seems it's about remote forms and not forms loaded via a partial:

Changed default value for config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms to false. This change breaks remote forms that need to work also without JavaScript, so if you need such behavior, you can either set it to true or explicitly pass authenticity_token: true in form options.

Found answer here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10608